# Who owns a player that is on loan?

Tags: football, transfer

Does a club still own a player when they loan him to different club?

For example, I know Chelsea loaned Fernando Torres to AC Milan, where he was disastrous and now is loaned to Athletico Madrid.

So is he still a Chelsea player or was he loaned from AC Milan to Athletico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The team who loans a player from another team doesn't own them, but they usually pay his wages. Often teams will loan out players who are too young/inexperienced to play for their main team, since they can gain experience and they don't have to pay their wages.

If Team A sign a player, but he's too young/inexperienced to play for them, they will often him out to other teams on loan. So say they loan him out to Team B, this means Team A still own the rights to him, but while he's on loan, they don't have to pay the wages because Team B will pay the wages.

Although, the case of Torres is a little different. Torres was on loan from Chelsea since the start of the season, however in the mid-season transfer window, Milan got Torres on a free transfer deal, so Milan are now the owners of him. As soon as the deal was completed, they loaned Torres to Atletico Madrid, in exchange for Alessio Cerci.

Unusually in this situation however, instead of Milan paying the wages of Cerci, and Atletico paying the wages of Torres, as is fairly usual for a loan deal, Milan are paying the wages of Torres, and Atletico are paying the wages of Cerci.

Torres gets paid £4m/year and Cerci gets paid £2.5m/year

Comment: The math doesn't work out well for Milan. Not sure why they went for Torres. Or they might have been looking for Cerci but they landed Torres first. Whatever, I just want a good game and Torres to be at his prime again.

Comment: @rageit it's like the Marcos Rojo deal between Manchester United and Sporting Lisbon. Man United were so desperate for Rojo, they not only paid £16m for Rojo, but also loaned Nani out to Sporting for the entire season, and will pay his wages as well. I guess Milan just did whatever they had to do to get rid of Torres and get Cerci.

Comment: @cantsay That played out pretty well but it was unfortunate for Rojo to get injured. Anyway I'd like Torres to get back to his previous self.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Torres):

> Fernando José Torres Sanz [...] is a Spanish professional footballer who plays for Italian club Milan, on loan from English club Chelsea [...]. He will make a permanent move to Milan effective from 5 January 2015 but will be loaned to Atlético Madrid.

So as of right now (2nd January 2015) he is a Chelsea player, but he will be an AC Milan player from 5th January.

Comment: Alright I get it. He would be a Milan player.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I'm editing the question to make the Torres question a specific example of the more general question. That way this question will still be useful in the future when he moves on or retires.